# Posts in Categories not be display in a second language

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I'm using Polylang Plugin for translate my website. In second lang posts in none of the categories not be show! In option reading - max post number value is 10. While in a category I have less than 10 posts it work but for 11 posts or more posts not be display in category!!! How can I fix this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying - is the category page empty in the second language? Or you have just the first page of posts without any pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was just CSS style(RTL properties) I cleared that and now it is working fine. Thank You.